# How to add custom tags to DICOM Dataset using EvilDicom?

Tags: c#, dicom

I'm working with EvilDicom. I have the requirement to add some custom tags (for example Patient's ID Card Number Mobile Phone Number and Address) to DICOM dataset. Has any one ever done this?

```
DICOMFile dFile = new DICOMFile();
dFile.PATIENT_BIRTH_DATE.Data = DateTime.Now;
        dFile.PATIENT_TELEPHONE_NUMBERS.Data = "";
        dFile.PATIENT_SEX.Data = "Male";
        dFile.PATIENT_MOTHER_BIRTH_NAME.Data = "baby of";
        //dFile.birth_order --> need to add this 
        dFile.PATIENT_ID.Data = "";
        dFile.CREATION_DATE.Data = DateTime.Now;
        //dFile.visit_number --> need to add this 
        dFile.LOCATION.Data = "";
        //dFile.birth_weight --> need to add this 
        //dFile.gestationAge --> need to add this
```

I am working for ophthalmic photography modality, I need to create new DicomTags for different custom values. It would be very helpful if you give me a hint on it.

Comment: Also take a look at this documentation http://rexcardan.github.io/Evil-DICOM/articles/operations.html#replacing-and-removing-elements

Comment: Although the toolkit is different, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57181536/5779732) explains Private Tags in details. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65121332/5779732) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need before implementing anything is a full specification of the DICOM data structures based on the [Information Object Definition](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/chapter_A.html) (IOD) in the DICOM standard. Storing telephone numbers of the patient in a Composite DICOM IOD (e.g. ophthalmic photography image) usually makes no sense since DICOM objects are archived for 10, 20 or 30 years in a PACS (Picture Archiving and Communication System), i.e. they are not modified after their creation, e.g. in order to reflect the current contact information of the patient.

In fact, the DICOM standard does define attributes such as Patient's Telephone Numbers​ (0010,2154)​ and Patient's Telecom Information​ (0010,2155)​ but not for using them in a Composite IOD but to be queried from the departmental information system using the network service DICOM [Modality Worklist Management](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part04/chapter_K.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I wanted to try to answer this in case anyone else came in and was looking to do this as well.
The first thing you should do is figure out which tag you want to add and its type.
https://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/dicom-tags/

Pay close attendion to the VR types as they'll be useful.

Then take a look at the types of elements that evilDicom expects in the open source.
https://github.com/rexcardan/Evil-DICOM/tree/master/EvilDICOM/EvilDICOM/Core/Element
So for instance, when I came across this, I needed to add a CollimatorType Dicom tag (0018,1181). The type is CS for code string.

Then if we look at the constructor for the code string element, we see:

```
public CodeString(Tag tag, string data)
        {
            Tag = tag;
            Data = data;
            VR = VR.CodeString;
        }
```

As you see the constructor inputs a Tag and a string to set the DData attribute. So you could write some code like this.

```
var dcm = DICOMObject.Read(file);
                            //add required tags to dicom object
                            var collimatorType = new CodeString(TagHelper.CollimatorType, "Unknown");
                            dcm.ReplaceOrAdd(collimatorType);
```

Then you can rinse and repeat for all the dicom objects you need to add.